# Insert Multiple Column Data From One Table to Another

Tags: mysql

I have two tables...

```
Table 1
------------
Col 1a
Col 1b
Col 1c

Table 2
------------
Col 2a
Col 2b
Col 2c
```

How would I write a MySQL statement to copy data from Col 1a to Col 2a, Col 1b to Col 2b and Col 1c to Col 2c all at once?

Answer (score 5):

```
INSERT Table2 (Col2a, Col2b, Colc2)
SELECT Col1a, Col1b, Col1c FROM Table1
```